Issue with deploying Angular application to gh-pages
I have an Angular application that I'm attempting to deploy to gh-pages via angular-cli-ghpages. I've been struggling off and on with this project, in general. I can either get my application working locally in order to test functions or I can successfully deploy, but never both. The deployed page's console provides 404 errors associated with access to the build files (.css, .js, etc.). Everything appears to be in place, even when I look at the gh-pages branch 'root' directory.
To this point, I've tried deleting the 'dist' directory, rebuilding using ng build --configuration production, then redeploying the app using either ng deploy --repo=https://github.com/tyler-kunce/myFlix-Angular-client.git or ngh --dir=dist/my-flix-angular-client. I've even tried uninstalling and installing angular-cli-ghpages as well as trying uninstalling angular-cli-ghpages then deploying my app using git command lines. Nothing seems to be consistently successful and I'm at my (and ChatGPT's, which I've been leveraging with a good chunk of the troubleshooting to-date) limits.
Hoping someone here can help. My Github repo is myFlix-Angular-client. My deployed app is text. Feel free to let me know if any other info would help as well.
Thanks in advance,
Tyler

You need to define base bases, because you are referencing the script files from root (https://tyler-kunce.github.io), but the application has been published to a sub folder (https://tyler-kunce.github.io/myFlix-Angular-client/). This results in 404 for all the files. You can configure the base path by changing the deployment cli call.

You may be interested in setting your <base> or using --deploy-url in your ng build command

Thanks for the replies! Forgive me as I'm still really new to web development and coding, in general. Reading the documentation, do I need to make any updates to the angular.json or index.html files? It didn't seem overly clear if that was the case or if it's done by the command line prompts.

I also added this post to the Angular Discord server. Someone suggested updating the package.json with "deploy" to point towards the base-href location. I did that, committed my updates to Github, ran 'ng build', the redeployed 'ng deploy'. Oddly enough and despite doing that, my Github repo still says my last deployment was 3 days ago rather than now. Somehow the CLI prompts are actually pushing anything to gh-pages despite the status saying otherwise.
